# Finding element with a specific tag at a specific point on a webpage

Tags: javascript, c#, html, browser

I am using `WebBrowser.Document.GetElementFromPoint()` to get an element at a specific x-y point on a webpage.  However, sometimes this feature doesn't work as expected, and it returns elements I don't want.  Maybe the ones I want are at the same location, but behind or in front of it?

Two questions:

1. How does `Document.GetElementFromPoint()` decide what to get
   (since it only returns 1) if there are overlapping elements?
2. Is there a way to get an element from a point that contains a
   specific tag name, or class, or id?

Comment: Showing us the code you are trying to use would be helpfull!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

["The element to be returned is determined through hit testing."](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#dom-document-elementfrompoint) That is, it will return the topmost element.

There is no way to directly limit your search to a given selector, but you could use the old trick of adjusting z-indices of the returned element to a large negative number, then trying again, then adjusting z-indices, etc. until you've cycled down to the bottom of the stack. That will give you a complete collection of elements at that point, at which time you can filter them based on whatever criteria you want.